# jupyterlab doesn't display png image

Tags: python, markdown, jupyter-lab

jupyterlab fails to display png image:

`![title](image/filename.png)`

results in showing only displaying the title.

I have the following installation

```
JupyterLab v0.35.4
Known labextensions:
   app dir: /anaconda3/envs/learnco_projects/share/jupyter/lab
        @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager v0.38.1  enabled  OK
        @jupyterlab/toc v0.6.0  enabled  OK
        @mflevine/jupyterlab_html v0.1.4  enabled  OK
        @ryantam626/jupyterlab_code_formatter v0.1.9  enabled  OK
        jupyterlab-flake8 v0.2.4  enabled  OK
```

Thank for the help

Comment: Please no screenshots; add the (minimal amount of) HTML to reproduce your issue and include any error messages.

Comment: Edited the post as requested.

Answer (score 5):

One easy way to display image on a Jupyter notebook is using HTML chunk of code in a `Markdown cell`, here is an example:

```
<img src='./image/filename.png'>Image description</img>
```

Once you `run` the cell, the image and its description text should appear in place of the HTML code.

EDIT

This works with `jupyter lab` and `classic jupyter notebook`.

Comment: Question is about jupyterlab, and answer is about jupyter notebook.  They are not identical and results vary.

Comment: @MarkAndersen This answer works fine in Jupyter Lab. Jupyter Lab suffers from the same propensity for broken image embeddings, and this answer fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

1- Have the notebook open in JupyterLab.
2- Right-click on the tab of the notebook and select `New View for Notebook`

The new view of the notebook should load with all figures successfully loaded.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).